# Можно ли изъять данные из ssd со сломанными контактами?

Tags: железо, ssd

Комп не видит ssd. Возможно сломаны контакты. Можно как то изъять данные?

Comment: Отнесите в сервис, наверное? Вряд ли мы продиагностируем ваш ssd по удалёнке

Comment: Из разряда: у меня комп сломался, почини, ты ж программист